# gRPC client - to - client communication between other Lan network

Tags: microservices, message-queue, pubsub

I have a question about gRPC communication.

I know gRPC has 4 models communication: unay, server-streaming, client-streaming and bi-direction. And the terms "client" and "server" very flexible, because it really is peer-to-peer communication.

I wonder "Can gRPC supports client-to-client communcation in case two or many clients locate in different LAN network"? Like image bellow:
[image]

For example, in MQTT protocol, two clients locate in different LAN network can communicate through topic in MQTT broker.

If pure gRPC can't support this model, can I add other ingredient to make gRPC support this communication?

Comment: It's just a matter of network connectivity.  If two machines need to talk to each other then can one open an http(s) connection to the other?  If so: good!  If not: bad.  gRPC is a communication between _two_ machines and only two machines. (Per conversation.)

Comment: @davidbak Because I want to use grpc as communication protocol in IoT network  which many devices have unstable IP address, so I ask question.

Comment: well, that's kind of a _different_ problem: you're going to need some kind of locator service if the IP addresses keep changing.  But it sounds like you're thinking of MQTT or other message brokers as a pub/sub model, where everyone, producer and consumer, talks to a broker (or network of connected brokers) such that the broker has fixed IP address.  You could _write_ such a broker to talk gRPC ... but it wouldn't be native.  So the answer is: Not out of the box, but if you're willing to build a message queuing system yourself then you can build one that speaks gRPC.

Comment: @davidbak I have researched about combine Redis server publish/subscribe with grpc. Another approach may be RabbitMQ or Kafka. But I don't have may experience with this technology. Which one should I use? Please.